# How can I remove that "Ctrl" sign when I using Wacom pen in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, windows, wacom

when I using Wacom pen in Photoshop CC (Windows 10) and clicking "Cntrl" button it appears "Cntrl" sign which distracts attention and annoying, is there a way to remove it? I was trying to make some adjustments in Wacom Tablet Properties but without success.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of Windows Ink.

- Good news: it can be disabled
- Bad news: this might break pressure sensitivity in Photoshop
- Good news: this can be fixed

First of all, open your Wacom preferences, find `Use Widows Ink` option and disable it:

[image]

Next, restart Photoshop and see if pressure sensitivity works normally. If it doesn't:

1. paste this path to File Explorer: `%appdata%\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019\Adobe Photoshop CC 2019 Settings` (change 2019 to your version if needed): this will open `Roaming` user folder;
2. create a new text file in there called `PSUSerConfig.txt`;
3. in this file paste these lines:

   `# Use WinTab
   UseSystemStylus 0`

and save it. This directive says to Photoshop to use WinTab driver instead of Windows Ink.

[image]

Restart Photoshop and pressure sensitivity should work fine.

Comment: this is fantastic. Really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: If the answer worked for you please check it as an accepted answer for everyone to find it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's a strong likelihood that your settings for the mouse are set to show the circle. Open your control panel or use the search feature for Mouse, select Pointer Options and turn off the checkbox.  The above information was derived from [isunshare web site](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/show-pointer-location-with-ctrl-key-in-windows-10.html).

[image: mouse pointer options]